# Reusable AWS Glue Job

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

I have over 200 tables which need to be migrated to S3 from RDBMS with no transformations So we are planning to migrate using Glue Job. So I want to create AWS Glue Job which can be re-usable and executed using parameter values so that i can run for multiple tables at a time(Multi-threading). Is this possible anyway in AWS Glue.

Answer (score 3):

The quick answer is yes

1. You can reuse a singular glue job that can be resued where you can pass your source location and target database table name as job arguments to the glue job
2. Your glue jobs supports concurrency which can be set in your glue job(whcih means you can have multiple invocations of the same job). This would be the easier option than implementing multi-threading in your job. But multi-threading would cretainly be possible as long as we use only default or pure python modules. There are certain account level limits (which can be increased) that you will need to keep in mind.
3. You can pass the arguments to the glue job when you invoke the glue job, by using whatever mechanism you want (eg: step functions/lambdas...)

Comment: Thanks Emerson, in your point to you mentioned that we can have multiple invocations can those invocations be simultaneously? So that i will create one lambda or step function which will run for multiple tables parallel on using one Glue Job or Script in S3 folders.

Comment: Yes.. you can have multiple involcations simultaneously. And yes you can have a singluar lambda/step function running a single job/script and pass them different arguments at run time ( although some executions might go beyond the lambda time limit ..so you might end up using step functions)